# Appache Flink - custom truststore

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Hi I am using Flink version: 1.6.0.
I need to set custom truststore for java so I added to `flink-conf.yaml` property

`env.java.opts: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/tls/certs/xxx -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=zzz"`

But in than in code in my class which is child of `RichFlatMapFunction` in `flatMap` method run

```
LOG.info("> javax.net.ssl.trustStore ${System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")}")
```

I got null. So this property is not set.

Can you pls give me some hint why it is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem is with the order how the services are started. I need to first start taskmanager service on all 3 instances of flink a than I can submit job. 
Hope the this will help for somebody :-)